# Swift: For Loop Wait Until Response And Return Value According To Response

Tags: swift, database, networking

I'm new to swift and I'm practicing networking.

I have a list of kids ID's. Full kids info is stored in a Firebase Database. Each kid in the database has an `ID` and a property `isGamer: Bool`.
I want to create a function which will return the first kid where `isGamer==true.`
The logic I was thinking about is:
A for loop, which will run on the list and will check for the first kid if `isGamer == true` if so, return kid's ID, else continue searching. 
I think it would work though I have no idea how to deal with all these asynchronous stuff, how can I make a for loop wait for response etc.

The main function will manage everything:

```
// Mother Function
func printFirstGamer(kidsIds: [String]) {
     print(returnFirstKidIsGamer(kidsIds: kidsIds ))
}
```

Another function will find the first kid where isGamer==true:

```
// This is where I'm stuck basically

func returnFirstKidIsGamer(kidsIds: [String]) -> String {
    for kidID in kids {
        // Wait for previous request to finish before trying again.
        DataService.instance.isKidAGamer(kidID: kidID) { (isGamer) in

        }
        // The for loop will wait for response and then if isGamer==false, will continue, if isGamer==true will return 
    }
    // return first kid where isGamer == true

}
```

I will use this function to check isGamer for each kid:

```
func isKidAGamer(kidID: String, completed: @escaping isKidAGamerCompleted) {
        mainRef.child("Kids").child(kidID).child("isGamer").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (result) in
            if result.exists() {
                let isGamer = result.value as! Bool
                completed(isGamer)
            } else {
                completed(false)
            }
        })
    }
```

**note: I don't want to use queries, I'm practicing (:**

Thanks (:

Comment: Which asynchronous API are you using?  Link or paste the declaration.  I suspect it takes a block.  You don't want a for loop, you want to check the result in the success block and if `isGamer == false` recursively call the function.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include what you have tried so far. Clearly indicate what part you need help with.

Comment: I think instead of using for loop you need to create operation to get kid info. After completion of opration check if isGamer == true, if not than perform same operation again with different kid id.

Comment: Even practicing, you really can't avoid using asynchronous queries. It's fundamental to how iOS works. Converting your async system into a synchronous system (even in a hackish way that blocks the main thread) is a more advanced topic than the one you're avoiding (you'll need a DispatchGroup, for example, which is much more complicated than async). You really have to learn to deal with async, even from the very beginning.

Comment: @rmaddy I added some more info, sorry for that. I'm using firebase, and i hope everything will be more clear now (:

Comment: @RobNapier I don't have an intention to block the main thread, just let the user wait (with an activityIndicator) until there's a response... Anyone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible to make this synchronous using a DispatchGroup, but this must never be called on the main queue.

```
// Blocking function. Must not be called on main queue!
func returnFirstKidIsGamer(kidsIds: [String]) -> String? {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var result: String? = nil

    for kidID in kidsIds {
        // Wait for previous request to finish before trying again.
        group.enter()
        DataService.instance.isKidAGamer(kidID: kidID) { (isGamer) in
            if isGamer {
                result = kidId
            }
            group.leave()
        }
        group.wait()
        guard result == nil else { break }
    }
    return result
}
```

This calls `group.enter()` before entering each loop, and `group.leave()` when each step completes. It then waits for the step to complete before moving on.

This function is synchronous. It blocks the queue and so must never be called on the main queue. You have to move it to the background with something like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    let kidId = returnFirstKidIsGamer(kidsIds: [kids])
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        doSomethingInTheUIWithValue(kidId)
    }
}
```

Note that this returns `String?`, not `String`, since no id may be found.

As a rule, you shouldn't do this. You should use a query. But this is how you make asynchronous functions into synchronous functions when needed.